# Request: Have a "Revisit Question" queue for users.

Tags: discussion, feature-request

First of all I would like to give credit at Opera for the feature called **Stash** which they recently brought in the browser.My request is kinda inspired from it.

**Motivation**

I just started using the mobile application and its nice for reading stuff, maybe a comment or two but still I prefer to have the comfort of a PC to write a proper answer.

There are even times(this is less often) when we  read a question and due to any reason we are unable to answer it at that point of time but will still like to answer it later.

At often times it may happen that I forget the about question or may find it difficult to find it , if its about a high frequency topic(Like HTML5 ,Javascript ) ,and now when stackexchange has so many websites and a unified app this things start to stand out a bit more.

**Solution**

So I would like to propose that we can have a similar feature like  **Stash** in the website where a user can quickly add a question to the  **Revisit Question Queue** (or something similar),and the user gets notification about the question in the queue periodically, or he can manually revisit it later.

I know that the current workaround is that the user can favorite a question and then revisit it , but still I feel that favoriting a question/answer is conceptually different from what we are trying to achieve, and also finding a question that I Favorited previously for answering is kind of difficult if you have a long list of Favorites

Comment: At the moment I use my favourites to mark a question for revisiting as you've pointed out - and I mark questions for revisiting when I want to bounty them to reward an exceptional answer. This would be useful, at the very least as a separate list - I'm not so keen on the reminders myself.

Comment: I'm also using favorite currently, but sometimes it's a bit mess since... I use favorite mark to mark the questions I am interested to too. I think this is a good idea, though not urging, since you can sort the favorite by the time it's added.

Comment: I'm not sure about a queue, that seems to imply first in first out and only viewing in the order posts were added. Personally I'd like (custom) categories added to favourites i.e. when favouriting you get a popup asking for a category. When viewing you can filter them by category.